# How do I successfully serve a local Laravel app on my phone without the connection refused error?

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

I'm running a Laravel 9 app on my MacBook using `php artisan serve`. I would like to see the app on my Android phone, but I'm failing.

Both the computer and the phone are connected to the same WiFi network. I serve the app on my computer and access its public IP:port on my phone, like this:

HTTP://192.168.1.10:8000

However, all I'm getting is an error in Chrome: `Err_Connection_Refused`. Tried Firefox as well.

What might be wrong or missing here?

Comment: And your command is: `sudo php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.10 --port 8080` ?

Comment: If that is the command you are using .. Your Mac might be blocking with a firewall ..

Comment: @Zak Nope. But now it is and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full `artisan` command for running a Laravel application that you want reached from other devices is

```
sudo php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.10 --port 8080
```

This opens up listening to the **external** port of `8080` for **incoming** traffic from outside `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`